# get a list of iconNames from office UI fabric

Tags: office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react

How can i get a list of valid IconNames from office UI fabric. I am trying to create an icon Picker for an spfx webpart. I've tried importin IconNames from @uiFabric/icons :
import{IconNames} from "@uifabric/icons"
but i get an error : const enum use is deprcated.

Thanks
Russell

Answer (score 0):

The [Icon.SvgFactory.Example](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/master/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Icon/examples/Icon.SvgFactory.Example.tsx) shows how to enumerate the icons defined in the @fluentui-react-icons library.

```js
const icons = Object.keys(ReactIcons).reduce((acc: React.FC[], exportName) => {
  if (!!(ReactIcons as any)[exportName].displayName) {
    acc.push((ReactIcons as any)[exportName] as React.FunctionComponent);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
```